# php - quick refactoring

Tags: php, refactoring

I have 2 methods, that are pretty much exactly the same and I'd likie someone to help me refactor them:

```
public static function searchFromVideoRequest($word, $returnPropelObjects = false)
{
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->addJoin(YoutubeVideoPeer::ID,ItemPeer::YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
    $c->addSelectColumn(self::TITLE);
    $c->addSelectColumn(self::ID);
    $c->add(ItemPeer::TITLE, '%'.$word.'%', Criteria::LIKE);
    $c->addAnd(self::YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID, null, Criteria::ISNOTNULL);
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::TITLE);
   if ($returnPropelObjects)
          return self::doSelect($c);

        $stmt = self::doSelectStmt($c);
        $results = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
}

public static function searchFromFlickrRequest($word, $returnPropelObjects = false)
{
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->addJoin(FlickrPhotoPeer::ID,ItemPeer::FLICKR_PHOTO_ID);
    $c->addSelectColumn(self::TITLE);
    $c->addSelectColumn(self::ID);
    $c->add(ItemPeer::TITLE, '%'.$word.'%', Criteria::LIKE);
    $c->addAnd(self::FLICKR_PHOTO_ID, null, Criteria::ISNOTNULL);
    $c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::TITLE);
   if ($returnPropelObjects)
          return self::doSelect($c);

        $stmt = self::doSelectStmt($c);
        $results = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean: you want someone to refactor them for you. Or do you have any specific problem with your attempt at refactoring? If so, show us your attempt and describe in which way it does not work.

Comment: And you can't do this yourself because?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've tried to replace the  `   if ($returnPropelObjects)
          return self::doSelect($c);

        $stmt = self::doSelectStmt($c);
        $results = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
}
` into another method and simply call that in both functions, but that hasn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refactor such methods you can split up them into a few methods that will contain common code and make them private, so no one can use them outside the class:

```
public static function searchFromVideoRequest($word, $returnPropelObjects = false)
{
    $c = self::buildSearchCriteria($word);
    $c->addJoin(YoutubeVideoPeer::ID,ItemPeer::YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
    $c->addAnd(self::YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID, null, Criteria::ISNOTNULL);
    return self::getSearchResult($c, $returnPropelObjects);
}

public static function searchFromFlickrRequest($word, $returnPropelObjects = false)
{
    $c = self::buildSearchCriteria($word);
    $c->addJoin(FlickrPhotoPeer::ID,ItemPeer::FLICKR_PHOTO_ID);
    $c->addAnd(self::FLICKR_PHOTO_ID, null, Criteria::ISNOTNULL);
    return self::getSearchResult($c, $returnPropelObjects);
}

private static function buildSearchCriteria($word)
{
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->addSelectColumn(self::TITLE);
    $c->addSelectColumn(self::ID);
    $c->add(ItemPeer::TITLE, '%'.$word.'%', Criteria::LIKE);
    $c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::TITLE);
    return $c;
}

private static function getSearchResult($c, $returnPropelObjects)
{
    if ($returnPropelObjects)
      return self::doSelect($c);

    $stmt = self::doSelectStmt($c);
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

PS: And I think the question is OK.