# PHP PDO error in multi-statement query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I ran in to this problem in one of my live web apps.  It seems that if you issue a multi-statement query to MySQL via PHP PDO, and the first statement is an insert statement, and the second statement is an update statement, the PDO::nextRowset() function doesn't return the right number of result sets.  (Note that PDO supposedly supports multiple statements per MySQL query since PHP 5.3.)

Here's an example:

**SQL:**

```
create database `test`character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
create table `test`.`testtable`( `id` int );
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$link = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');

//Run one of the 4 $handle assignments at a time (comment out all but one). 
//Run #4 on an empty table to compare the results of #1 and #4.

//WORKS: INSERT, followed by SELECT, followed UPDATE
//Output: 
//Rowset 1
//Rowset 2
//Results detected
$handle = $link->prepare(' insert into testtable(id) values(1);
                           select * from testtable where id = ?;
                           update testtable set id = 2 where id = ?;');


//WORKS: SELECT, followed by UPDATE
//Output: 
//Rowset 1
//Results detected
$handle = $link->prepare('select * from testtable where id = ?; 
                          update testtable set id = 2 where id = ?;');

//WORKS: UPDATE, followed by SELECT
//Output: 
//Rowset 1
//Rowset 2
//Results detected
$handle = $link->prepare('select * from testtable where id = ?; 
                         update testtable set id = 2 where id = ?;');


//DOESN'T WORK: INSERT, followed by UPDATE, followed by SELECT
//Output: 
//Rowset 1
//Expected output: same as examples 1 and 3
$handle = $link->prepare('insert into testtable(id) values(1);
                          update testtable set id = 2 where id = ?;
                          select * from testtable where id = ?;');

$handle->bindValue('1', '1');
$handle->bindValue('2', '2');

$handle->execute();

$i = 1;
do{
    print('Rowset ' . $i++ . "\n");
    if($handle->columnCount() > 0)
     print("Results detected\n");
}while($handle->nextRowset());
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?  Why can't I put my select statement at the end?

PHP 5.3.5

MySQL 5.1.54

Comment: should one be using \PDO

Comment: You shouldn't be doing multiple queries in a single query call to begin with. The mysql client libraries for PHP, which PDO uses, do not support this as an sql injection prevention defense.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone One should, if one is developing within a namespace

Comment: PDO supports multiple statements per query as of PHP 5.3, so the question isn't whether or not one should do that, but why the above example is giving strange results.

Comment: @MarcB this is interesting. apparently pdo switched mysql drivers in php 5.3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: @AlexCabal : Would you please mention the links where its is written that  multiple query is supported by PDO

Comment: @diEcho see above comments for the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I submitted a [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61207) about this problem and a possible patch has been submitted.  So it looks like this was a PHP bug.

Answer (score 0):

1. First , you have to figure out what will nextRowset() returns regarding of a non-select operation . I have tried to var_dump it after an update ,and I got bool(false), which can explain why you only get one output with :

   ```
   $handle = $link->prepare('insert into testtable(id) values(1);
                     update testtable set id = 2 where id = ?;
                     select * from testtable where id = ?;');
   ```
2. Second, I replaced the following codes:

   ```
   var_dump($h->nextRowset());
   var_dump($h->nextRowset());
   ```

   with your do-while segment,I got bool(false) bool(true), witch means that it just goes once in the loop.

   I don't know whether it is right to explain your question as above, may it will help you.