# Updating random records in 2 tables in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Given this tables structure,

```
categories{id}
product_models{id, category_id}
products{product_model_id, category_id}
```

Which is already populated, but with `product_models.category_id`, `products.category_id` and `products.product_model_id` all set to `NULL`, I need a single query that will "connect" them all, doing the follow:

1. set all `product_models.category_id`, to a random value from the `categories` table
2. set all `products.product_model_id`, to a random value from `product_models` table
3. set each `products.category_id`, to the value of the category_id of the newly assigned `product_models` record.

Can it be done in a SINGLE query?

Comment: you can achieve this by writing a stored procedure

Comment: can you give me some direction about the way to do it?

Comment: I can give you an example of how to it as an answer, if you wish, the general idea is to use cursors http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am able to understand you requirement, this is what you require

```
 Create Procedure usp_insert
 as
 begin
    declare @rand1 int
    declare @rand2 int
    set @rand1=rand()*10000
    set @rand2=rand()*10000

    insert into categories (id) values (@rand1)
    insert into product_models{id, category_id} values (@rand2,@rand1)
    insert into products{product_model_id, category_id} values (@rand2,@rand1)
End
```

above block will create a procedure in your database

to execute the procedure use following code

```
exec usp_insert
```

Each execution of the procedure will insert one row in each of the tables
e.g. 
suppose random numbers generated are 3423,2345
then it will 
1. insert a row in categories table with 3423 as id
2. insert a row in product_models table with 3423 as category_id and 2345 as id
3. insert a row in product_models table with 3423 as category_id and 2345 as product_model_id

you can adjust the insert queries according to your requirement.

Comment: great! seems like it's the solution, but, can't it be done with one pure sql query? using joins?

Comment: No, there is no way of doing this in a single step. You will need to perform multiple queries, and why do we need such query? it works fine without any problem. Also, we have converted it to a stored procedure, its as good as a single query for you.

Comment: I referred this link before putting above comment 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700810/using-pdo-to-insert-multiple-records-in-multiple-tables-from-one-statement

Answer (score 1):

No

The RAND function only executes once in any query and is effectively 'locked' to a single value no matter how many times it is used.