# PDO multiple queries understanding issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, subquery

Okay guys I am having a hard time understanding how to do a certain query.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

I am trying to output DISTINCT brands from a query result. So when a user searches for instance "SHOE" I can output all of the shoes in my database, plus have a choice on the side where the user can select a certain brand to filter the results. I already can output all of the data I need from the MATCH AGAINST query, I just can't figure out how to do ***A query that can query my first query with PDO***.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$usersearch=strip_tags($_POST['searchquery']);
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(brand) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE);SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM products");
$query->execute(array('+%'.$usersearch.'%','+%'.$usersearch.'%'));
$result=$query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

My problem is with the `"SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM products"`.

Is this the correct way to perform multiple queries? Will this select each brand `FROM THE FIRST QUERY` to the left of the semicolon or just perform the query on each row in the DB?

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm kind of at a stand still.

Comment: This (this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd/55169977#55169977) solution help you to run multiple query together,
If an incorrect a query occurs, it does not execute any other query.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot prepare and execute multi queries in one string with PDO.

You can use [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), but without preparing. But it useless for multi select.

You could use [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html), but count of selected fields must be the same. For example

```
SELECT brand FROM products 
    WHERE 
        MATCH(description) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        OR MATCH(brand) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM products
```

P.S. or just use two separated queries :^ )

Comment: Thank you sectus for your reply. I figured it out looping through an array and not echoing to screen any duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

I am posting this answer in case anyone else runs into this problem. I used an empty array to store each brand in and if any of the values matched, continue is used to pass it by.

```
<?php
    $emptyarray=array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $individualbrand=$row['brand'];
        if(in_array($individualbrand,$emptyarray))
            continue;
        $emptyarray[]=$individualbrand;
        for($i=0;$i<10;++$i)
            echo '<a href="#">'.$emptyarray[$i].'</a><br />';}
            ?>
```

This will output UNIQUE brand names from the database results. The empty array is created, populated while being checked for duplicates. Then a for loop iterates through each array value. (I used 10 because I don't think I'll have more than 10 brand names in all resulting from a search.) Hopefully this can help someone in the future.

Comment: Actually the last closing bracket needs to be right after the line:$emptyarray[]=$individualbrand;   Well sectus, maybe I shouldn't have asked it thinking I needed multiple queries to select distinct brands.  And one more thing, "Oh, God....This code works flawlessly with each database query that I send." What's wrong with creating an array with unique values and echoing with a for loop? I see nothing wrong, and again I will iterate for you: It worked for me.

Comment: 1. You can use pure sql for it.

Comment: 2. Your code has lack of logic (yes, brace was not in right place). 3. 'I used 10 because I don't think I'll have more than 10 brand names in all resulting from a search' - it's dirty way with notices.

Comment: 'It worked for me' -- it's normal. But try to produce nice code when you doing it for other.