# pdo defining a function an then using it in a select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-function

My query is somewhat like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION func ... ;
SELECT * FROM  ....;
```

I'm using php's `PDO` which doesn't allow more than 1 statements in a `$pdo->query()` , so instead I decided that I'd split the query into two, so I execute the `CREATE FUNCTION` query using `$pdo->exec()` and then use `$pdo->query()` on the select statement.

However, I get the error on execution of select statement that `FUNCTION database.func does not exist`. How do I solve this? when I run it in phpmyadmin as a single query it works fine

Edit : PHP code :

```
class MyClass {
function connectPDO($user,$pass,$chartset="utf8"){
    //simple function for making a new PDO object and mysql connection
    $dbname = "my_db";
    try {
        //creating new pdo
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $user,$pass);
        //attributes set to throw errors and exceptions which can be caught, can be changed
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //fetch associative arrays
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //default chartset
        $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "'.$chartset.'"');
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //on some error
        $output = "Ay caramba! there's something wrong here!.<br>";
        echo $output.$e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    $this->db = $pdo;
}
}

$object = new MyClass();
$object->connectPDO("user","pass");
$sqlPreliminary = "
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS myFunc;
        DELIMITER //

        CREATE FUNCTION myFunc (id INT)
            RETURNS DECIMAL

            BEGIN
            RETURN id + 1;
            END //
        DELIMITER ;

";

$sqlFinal = "
    SELECT id, myFunc(id) AS plusOne  FROM table;
";
$object->db->exec($sqlPreliminary);
var_dump($object->db->query($sqlFinal)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Comment: Does it exists after `CREATE`? I mean: do you add it but cannot use or is it not added at all?

Comment: When I execute only the part where function is created, pdo throws no error, so I'm assuming that it should be added. Is there a way to check it?

Comment: Try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-procedure-code.html

Comment: I'm afraid your function is not created. PDO::exec() does not return error. You might want to make PDO throw exceptions. If something goes wrong you will be noticed.

Comment: Could you possibly paste entire code of db statements?

Comment: i tried SHOW FUNCTION CODE func , doesn't work

Comment: Could you possibly paste entire PHP code?

Comment: I'm not pasting mysql code as it might confuse you, I'll try to give some demo code

Comment: Added mysql code to work with

Comment: Can you create function via shell or phpmyadmin and then use it in your queries?

P.S.: And are you sure you really need complicated logic in databas layer?

Comment: How will the function i create via phpmyadmin be persistent?

Answer (score 5):

Create a user defined function using PDO simply works by exec, no delimiter is required. Here $db is PDO instance.

```
$db->exec('CREATE FUNCTION ConvertHTMLToText(str LONGTEXT CHARSET utf8)
           RETURNS LONGTEXT CHARSET utf8
           BEGIN
           DECLARE start, end INT DEFAULT 1;
           LOOP
           SET start = LOCATE("<", str, start);
           IF (!start) THEN RETURN str; END IF;
           SET end = LOCATE(">", str, start);
           IF (!end) THEN SET end = start; END IF;
           SET str = TRIM(INSERT(str, start, end - start + 1, ""));
           END LOOP;
           END');
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

This is multiple statement. The first part is `DROP FUNCTION MyFunc IF EXISTS` and the second is `CREATE FUNCTION`.

*This was my previous answer, which was correct, but OP changed the code:*

You don't say what `$object->db` is:

You call `connectPDO("user","pass");` and then use `$object->db->exec($sqlPreliminary);`. `$object` should be global in function body. At the moment it is not, so it is a local variable, which is lost after end of the function. This `$object` in rest of the code is something different.

Comment: It isn't that simple. connectPDO is actually a part of a class. updated the code .

Comment: You should have posted this in the very beginning. The problem is that this IS multiple statement. There is `DROP ... IF EXISTS;`

Comment: yeah, but exec is capable of running multiple statements

Comment: I can't test it now, but [the first comment in the Manual](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php#71843) says it is not.

Comment: Making my queries individual works, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd says that exec does support multiple statements.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. When I removed  " DELIMITER // " (also  //
DELIMITER ; at the end),  it worked. I think DELIMITER is no longer required with PHP PDO.

```
$sqlPreliminary = "
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS myFunc;
   
    CREATE FUNCTION myFunc (id INT)
        RETURNS DECIMAL

        BEGIN
        RETURN id + 1;
        END 

";
```

I tested this and worked.