# PHP import sql from multiple directories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-get-contents

I am trying to create a script where I can import .sql files from multiple directories into my database.

I am able to import one SQL by this code:

```
<?php
$sql = file_get_contents('mysqls/hey.sql');
$qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
?>
```

But when I move on to make it read more then one .sql file it dosnt work:

```
<?php
$sql = file_get_contents('mysqls/*.sql');
$qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
?>
```

I would also like for it to go into multiple folders that may be created in the future [folders would be in the same directory as the code].

My database connection has already been made in a PDO config connection.

Comment: you need to traverse through each file

Answer (score 2):

```
$dirf    = 'mysqls';
$dir = scandir($dirf);
foreach($dir as $file) {
   if(($file!='..') && ($file!='.')) {
       $sql = file_get_contents($file);
       $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to show an success / error message?

Comment: success message for db query??

Comment: success/error depends on the db query only.so you can echo the success/error of db query in the if loop

Comment: Dont worry, relised how to do then removed as I no longer need the messages. Anyways the code you provided is not working correctly. Its reading the files, but for some reason its not running it through the database.

Comment: If it helps, in my .sql files I have similar codes of "INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'hello');"

Comment: i think in .sql files there are so many queries.I think php needs some other func , other than ->exec to run these.once check how to run multiple queries.check This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: even if I use only 1 .sql it still does not work.