# MySQL stops running queries after if statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now ...

Here's my code:

```
$SQLQuery1 = $db_info->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM menusize WHERE typesize=:typesize");
        $SQLQuery1->bindValue(':typesize',$_POST['typesize'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $SQLQuery1->execute();
        if($SQLQuery1->fetchColumn() > 0) {
            $SQLQuery2 = $db_info->prepare("INSERT INTO menucatagorysize (menucatagory_ID,menusize_ID) VALUES (:catagoryid,(SELECT ID FROM menusize WHERE typesize=:typesize))");
            $SQLQuery2->bindValue(':typesize',$_POST['typesize'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $SQLQuery2->bindValue(':catagoryid',$_POST['catagoryid'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $SQLQuery2->execute();
        } else {
            $SQLQuery2 = $db_info->prepare("INSERT INTO menusize (typesize) VALUES (:typesize);
                                            SET @menusizeid=LAST_INSERT_ID();
                                            INSERT INTO menucatagorysize (menusize_ID,menucatagory_ID) VALUES (@menusizeid,:catagoryid)");
            $SQLQuery2->bindValue(':typesize',$_POST['typesize'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $SQLQuery2->bindValue(':catagoryid',$_POST['catagoryid'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $SQLQuery2->execute();
        }
        $SQLQuery3 = $db_info->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(menuitem_ID) FROM menuprice WHERE menucatagory_ID=:catagoryid");
        $SQLQuery3->bindValue(':catagoryid',$_POST['catagoryid'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $SQLQuery3->execute();
        $rows = $SQLQuery3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So, it will run through the if statement fine, running `$SQLQuery1` and `$SQLQuery2` (Which ever one is required) without any problems, errors or warnings. But, if it runs the `else {` part of the code, it will not run $SQLQuery3. Any thoughts?

Thanks :D

EDIT: Got it to work by doing `$SQLQuery2=NULL` in the `else` statement ... Sucks that I still cant figure out why it wouldnt work the original way.

Comment: Prepare takes one query, and one query alone. So, make those 3 statements 3 seperate calls.

Comment: @Wrikken: Not *entirely* true - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6461110.

Comment: @eggyal: Ah, yes, only _real_ prepares, and depending on driver as well. You've certainly got a point, but as it would be a bit of bad practise and confusing for a beginner, let's not delve into that here ;)

Comment: Yeah ... Had a look around and still not found anything ... I've not had any problems before using multiple prepared statements in this way ... Just never before used it in an IF statement this way ... I'm just all confused now :(

Comment: Sorry, but this looks so messy :X

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to enforce a uniqueness constraint over the `typesize` column of your `menusize` table from within your application code.  However, the database can do this for you—which will make your subsequent operations much simpler:

```sql
ALTER TABLE menusize ADD UNIQUE (typesize)
```

Now, one can simply attempt to insert the posted value into the table and the database will prevent duplicates arising.  Furthermore, as documented under [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If a table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) inserts or updates a row, the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function returns the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. Exception: For updates, [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is not meaningful prior to MySQL 5.1.12. However, you can work around this by using [`LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Suppose that `id` is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. To make [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:
>
> ```sql
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
> ```

Therefore, you can do:

```php
$db_info->prepare('
  INSERT INTO menusize (typesize) VALUES (:typesize)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE typesize=LAST_INSERT_ID(typesize)
')->execute(array(
  ':typesize' => $_POST['typesize']
));

$db_info->prepare('
  INSERT INTO menucatagorysize
    (menusize_ID, menucatagory_ID)
  VALUES
    (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :catagoryid)
')->execute(array(
  ':catagoryid' => $_POST['catagoryid']
));

$stmt = $db_info->prepare('
  SELECT DISTINCT menuitem_ID
  FROM   menuprice
  WHERE  menucatagory_ID = :catagoryid
');
$stmt->execute(array(
  ':catagoryid' => $_POST['catagoryid']
));
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  // etc.
}
```

(As an aside, the English word is spelled cat**e**gory, not cat**a**gory.)