# Multiple queries/results (PDO/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form where people can submit any and all kinds of MySQL queries and as I am now moving from MySQLi to PDO I am wondering if there is any way to deal with multiple query results using PDO. So let's say that a user submits the following to the PDO query method via an HTML form:

```
SELECT * FROM `organisation`.`employee`;
SELECT * FROM `organisation`.`salary`;
```

Is there a way to deal with both results?

Comment: May I ask, why you are moving from mysqli to pdo?

Comment: From what I've heard, The PHP Group considers it to be the way forward for accessing databases. There doesn't seem to be any real performance difference although MySQLi may be a bit faster in very rare cirumstances. You get named parameters and PDO just feels more natural and logical.

Comment: First rumor is a total rubbish. Moreover, mysqli is already ahead by a mile. In fact, even if mysqli will cease further development, PDO will need ten years to reach the level mysqli offer in handling mysql queries.

Comment: Second one sounds strange for the task. Why do you need placeholders at all, if you are running just arbitrary sets of queries?

Comment: I was talking in general why I'm switching. In this case I don't but still, I don't want to be using two interfaces when one is good enough.

Comment: Then just look for the appropriate function in the PDO manual that is getting multiple results

Comment: That's what I started by doing. When you run a query function it returns a PDOStatement object. I don't see how one would do it with such an object.

Comment: Well, it seems you have found it. For some reason someone who had no idea of this function existence before, managed to spot it for you. "Stack Overflow - the best online manual reader one can get!" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the entry string by the delimiter of ";", cycle through the released array.

That'd be one way at least.

[Here's an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6461110/3234482).

Here's a [link to the PDOStatement::nextRowset page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php). Read the example.

Comment: But some SQL code like stored procedures can contain multiple delimiters right? That would split the code incorrectly. Also, if there is a semicolon in an insert statement, part of the text, it would requre more advanced parsing to detect.

Comment: I did not realize you're also looking to perform queries such as those. I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: That's what I meant by "any and all kinds of MySQL queries".

Comment: The page you linked to shows how to execute multiple queries but not how to get with multiple results.

Comment: Alright, I've edited my answer with something new! Maybe it will help.

Comment: I haven't tried the code yet but it seems to be what I'm looking for. I looked at all the methods of the object but because of the unusual terminology (nextRowset) I didn't bother to read about it. I thought it had something to do with rows and I was looknig for something like "nextResultset".

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad I could help, it did take some looking though since I've never used that method either!