# How can I get an error when running multiple queries with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm running multiple queries using PDO. If the second query fails, no Exception is thrown.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "
DELETE FROM car; 
INSERT INTO car(name, type) SELECT name, from FROM vehicle;
";

try {
    $db->exec($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

The above code executes without throwing an exception.

How can I make sure that all queries have run successfully? How can I check which queries have failed?

*P.S. I'm using PDO multi query to run MySQL dumps, but any valid .sql file should work.*

Comment: The best way would be to run them one at a time. Also, you have an SQL syntax error in your `INSERT` query - the `SELECT` statement needs another column name after `name, `

Comment: @Kryten I'm using PDO to run MySQL dumps. Splitting a dump up is a daunting task. The error in the example is on purpose.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, the only suggestion I have is to examine the `PDOException` in your `catch` block & see if it includes more details on the specific query that failed. Start with a `print_r($e)` in the `catch` block...

Comment: Would placing a `print_r($db->errorInfo());` in the catch block work?

Comment: The problem is that no PDOException is thrown.

Comment: One dirty way could be to split the sql-string at `;\n` and run each of them one-by-one. Dirty hack, but I think it would solve the problem. Edit: Darn, this was already suggested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer in using a prepared statement. After looping through all rowsets, I can check if the last query executed caused an error using `$stmt->errorInfo()`.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);

$sql = "
DELETE FROM car; 
INSERT INTO car(name, type) SELECT name, from FROM vehicle;
";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$i = 0;

do {
  $i++;
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());

$error = $stmt->errorInfo();
if ($error[0] != "00000") {
  echo "Query $i failed: " . $error[2];
  die();
}
```

Comment: in your solution if incorrect a statement occurs, execute any other statement but This (this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd/55169977#55169977) solution helps you to run multiple statement together,
If an incorrect a statement occurs, it does not execute any other statement

Answer (score 1):

Following code will show how to catch error while running multiple queries. Try avoiding using "DELIMITER //". Queries are generally separately by ";".

```
<?php
// Create SQL List
$sqlStatements = "SELECT 100;SELECT 200;SELECT 300; Error SELECT 400;SELECT 500;";

// Prepare and execute statements
$options = [\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test", 'root', '', $options);

// Prepare and execute
$error = false;
$statement = $db->prepare($sqlStatements);
$statement->execute();

// Check error
try{
    do{
        // Print Resultset
        $rowset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        var_dump($rowset);
    }while($statement->nextRowset());

}catch(\Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no clear&easy way to do that.

I think, the best way is to read dump file query-by-query and execute one query at a time.

You can also parse error message and extract problem line number if DB driver tells it (like 'unknown identifier 'blabla' **on line 666**').

Comment: That would get me from fire into the frying pan. It's very likely that the queries have ";" in their values. Also I don't wan't to put the emphasis on the format of the dump file. Any valid .sql file should do.