# How to check if db execute sql fails?

Tags: php, database, yii2

I use console command in Yii2 framework and want to import db schema file via execute() method:

```php
public function actionReset()
{
    $schemasPath = Yii::getAlias('@common') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $schemaFile = $schemasPath . 'schema.sql';
    try {
        $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(file_get_contents($schemaFile));
        $command->execute();

        Console::output('Schema imported.');
        return self::EXIT_CODE_NORMAL;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Console::error($e->getMessage());
    }
    return self::EXIT_CODE_ERROR;
}
```

Documentation says:

> This method should only be used for executing non-query SQL statement, such as INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE SQLs. No result set will be returned.

Run this as:

```
$ ./yii db/reset
```

produce no error/exceptions.

Run this as:

```
$ mysql -u{user} -p -hlocalhost -D{base} < schema.sql
```

produce:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 241: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON DEFAULT NULL
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci' at line 4

Because MariaDB 10.1 don't support JSON data type.
So, how to check if all queries/commands from $schemaFile was success? Trying find some Yii::$app->db->getLastError() - no result.
Hm, some ideas?

Comment: Surely Google would have found something?

Comment: Use http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html.. and catch errors

Comment: @DoubleH I use, but execute() don't throw any exceptions.

Comment: show you code  with exception management too ..  please

Comment: @scaisEdge, I did not change/set exception management - it's framework defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23258691/1829368, it's:

```
try {
    $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(file_get_contents($schemaFile));
    $command->execute();

    do { } while ($command->pdoStatement->nextRowset());

    Console::output('Schema imported.');
    return self::EXIT_CODE_NORMAL;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Console::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

A do-while loop with nextRowset() trigger \PDOException when first db query fails.