# PDO. Two SELECT, using BEGIN and COMMIT and get SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Tags: mysql, pdo

Here is query

```
 BEGIN; 
 SELECT NumberRenamed, ... FROM 2_1_paidused WHERE CreditAccount = ? AND ...; 
 SELECT NumberRenamed, ... FROM 2_1_paidused WHERE DebitAccount = ? AND  ...; 
 COMMIT;`
```

(`...` is long list with columns and conditions).

and get `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`.

Removed `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` and all works as expected without errors.

From my knowledge if more than one `SELECT`, then need to use `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` But appears that I am wrong. So, does it mean that it is allowed to use more than one `SELECT` without `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;`? Or my query is incorrect?

Comment: where did you get that "knowledge"?

Comment: You only need a transaction if you need to ensure consistency between the two queries. Whether that's necessary depends on the application.

Comment: Are you trying to do both queries in one call to PDO? PDO doesn't support multiple queries in one call.

Comment: You could find the answer to your question through a bare minimum of research.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do both queries in one call. Regarding "knowledge" possibly i misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are four SQL statements. You don't share any PHP code but the way you display the queries suggest that you launch them at once into a single database call. Apparently, [running multiple queries in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd) is quite tricky—no idea if you got it right.

In any case, your transaction code is redundant:

- PDO has builtin functions to [start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and [commit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) transactions. There's no need to run commands manually.
- You don't *write* into the database, thus transactions don't have any purpose anyway.

I'm pretty sure you just need to run your two `SELECT` queries separately.

---

**Edit:** perhaps you're confused with [BEGIN ... END](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/begin-end.html). That's an entirely different feature. In MySQL, you can only use it in the body of stored routines.

Comment: Yes, it is a single database call. Single, because I supposed, that single call would use less resources. Thanks for explanation

Comment: If you remove the transaction code and follow the advice in the linked question to issue a 2-query call, you shouldn't get an error. But I'm not sure there's a way to *fetch* the results (I've never tried).