# Mysql row number function cannot work with PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why does the code below does not work

```
$db = new PDO(...); //init the PDO

$query = $db->query("
             Set @ids := 0;
             SELECT username, @ids := @ids + 1 as id FROM user 
           ");

$query->execute();
```

If I didn't use mysql row number function it work find. So does it mean I cannot use mysql row number function with php?

Comment: You are using multiple queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: How posible can i fixed it? @Clarkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO doesn't allow multiple queries in a single call. You could do it by calling `$db->query()` multiple times: first do the `SET` query, then do the `SELECT`.

However, instead of multiple statements, you can do it all in a single query with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT username, @ids := @ids + 1 AS id
FROM user
JOIN (SELECT @ids := 0) AS var
```