# How to INSERT and UPDATE with PDO in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I have the following INSERT snippet that works fine:

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `rating`(`business_id`, `user_id`, `quality`, `service`, `value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(1, $business_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $query->bindParam(2, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $query->bindParam(3, $quality, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $query->bindParam(4, $service, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $query->bindParam(5, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $query->execute();
```

However I would like to update another table if the insert was successful.

I thought this would do it:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $sql      = "UPDATE users SET prestige = prestige + 5";
        $query    = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        }
```

But no luck, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Final Code that works:

```
        if ($query->execute()) {
            $sql      = "UPDATE user SET prestige = prestige + 250
            WHERE id = {$user_id}";
            $query = $dbh->query($sql);
        }
```

Comment: `if ($query->execute()) {` replacing that from `$query->execute();` that should do it. You will need a `WHERE` clause though. Otherwise, that will update all your rows. Plus doing `$query    = $dbh->query($sql);`

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd is similar

Comment: You dont need prepare just execute it directly if you dont have params

Comment: @Mihai Yeah you're right, I just spotted that now. OP just needs to do `$query = $dbh->query($sql);`

Comment: @Mihai OP's not responding, so maybe they've gone out to get us all some lunch. If you're up to giving an answer, be my guest ;-) You've basically set the pace.

Comment: Sorry, internet died on me! @Fred-ii-, so is my original code close? I just need to add a WHERE clause and add `$query = $dbh->query($sql);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $sql      = "UPDATE users SET prestige = prestige + 5";
        $query = $dbh->query($sql);

        }
```

Just use query since you dont need prepared statements.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what I would include in the foreach section with this... :/

Comment: @potts Oops there an UPDATE.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the original post with the final answer that works :-)

Answer (score 0):

[execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. so this code must work. i think your problem is 'if ($stmt->execute())' you should check 'if ($query->execute())'

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `rating`(`business_id`, `user_id`, `quality`, `service`, `value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(1, $business_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $query->bindParam(2, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $query->bindParam(3, $quality, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $query->bindParam(4, $service, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $query->bindParam(5, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);

    if ($query->execute()) {
        $sql      = "UPDATE users SET prestige = prestige + 5";
        $query    = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
    }
```