# PHP PDO MySQL No Exception or Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got the following script that uses PDO.

```
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    $sql    = "BEGIN;\n".
              "INSERT INTO exp_ws_gk_text (WGT_PRG_CODE, WGT_TEXT)\n".
              "    VALUES('".$_POST['prg_code']."', ".$db->quote($_POST['text']).");\n" .
              "SELECT @Lid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();\n" .
              "INSERT INTO exp_ws_gk_state (WGS_STATE, WGS_TYPE, WGS_WGT_RID)\n".
              "    VALUES('".$_POST['state']."', ".$_POST['type'].", @Lid);\n".
              "SELECT a.wgt_prg_code prg_code, b.wgs_state state, b.wgs_type type, a.wgt_rid id, a.wgt_text text\n".
              "    FROM exp_ws_gk_text a\n".
              "    JOIN exp_ws_gk_state b ON b.wgs_wgt_rid = a.wgt_rid\n".
              "    WHERE b.wgs_wgt_rid = @Lid ORDER BY a.wgt_prg_code;\n".
              "COMMIT;\n";

$fp = fopen("/var/tmp/save_gatekeeper.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, "SQL:". $sql."\n");

    try {
        $res = $db->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute();
        $error = $db->errorInfo();

fwrite($fp, "ErrorInfo:".print_r($error, true)."\n\n");
fwrite($fp, "Row:      ".print_r($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), true)."\n\n");
fwrite($fp, "Row2:     ".print_r($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY),true)."\n\n");

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {

fwrite($fp, "ExceptionInfo:".print_r($e, true)."\n\n");

    }    

fclose($fp);

    echo json_encode($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC););
```

This is what the log produced:

```
SQL:BEGIN;
INSERT INTO exp_ws_gk_text (WGT_PRG_CODE, WGT_TEXT)
    VALUES('EDS', '[h3]IMPORTANT INFORMATION[/h3][p]This is a test gatekeeper for [b]Eddie\'s[/b] Classroom Course[/p]');
SELECT @Lid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO exp_ws_gk_state (WGS_STATE, WGS_TYPE, WGS_WGT_RID)
    VALUES('AL', 1, @Lid);
SELECT a.wgt_prg_code prg_code, b.wgs_state state, b.wgs_type type, a.wgt_rid id, a.wgt_text text
    FROM exp_ws_gk_text a
    JOIN exp_ws_gk_state b ON b.wgs_wgt_rid = a.wgt_rid
    WHERE b.wgs_wgt_rid = @Lid ORDER BY a.wgt_prg_code;
COMMIT;

ErrorInfo:Array
(
    [0] => 00000
)


Row:      

Row2:
```

I'm not sure why it isn't reporting any kind of error or exception. This is the 
first time I'm using PDO. I converted from using the older mysql calls.

Can someone help out here?

I'm expecting the results from the last select to be sent back, all I get is "false";

Comment: Is this a situation where you should be using `fetchAll`?

Comment: Don't know as it is the first time using PDO.

Comment: If you're pulling in multiple database rows, you want to use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch`. Use `fetch` if you want to return a single, specific row (via a unique or primary key).

Comment: Using `fetchAll()` only returned an empty array. I **know** that the record was inserted.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're doing an INSERT, not a SELECT. I should have been paying more attention. Try `query`.

Comment: on which line should I put it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76578/discussion-between-mb34-and-david-wyly).

Comment: FYI `$db->errorInfo();` retrieves error information on the handle and not on the prepared statement. `$res->errorInfo();` returns error information on your prepared statement. Not your issue but thought you should know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers, we solved this in chat.

You're mixing multiple types of statements. You need to separate out your queries into two separate queries; one with the `INSERT` with `$res->query`, and then validate the response, and then another with the `SELECT` using `$res->fetch()` or `$res->fetchAll()`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a prepared statement with multiple queries, you need to use emulated prepared statements.  Refer to [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO_MYSQL, PDO_MYSQLND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
```

Otherwise, I believe the only thing you are executing is `BEGIN;`

---

In my personal opinion, I think this is bad practice to put multiple queries into one PDO statement.  You should consider using a [transaction with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and multiple statements which allows you to more easily figure which query is causing issues and rollback if an error occurs.

---

Secondly, you are using prepared statements but are still not protecting yourself from SQL injections.  Don't use $_POST in the prepare().  You are supposed to bind those after you prepare the statement.