# PDO::exec multiple create tables in one string

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a project with multiple tables. All of those tables have a `create table if not exists` in a file named database.sql.

I wanted to execute this file containing severals `create table` in PDO. The problem is that it only execute the first `create table` of the file.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$sql = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . self::PATH_DATABASE_FILE);

$this->mPdoConnection->exec($sql);
```

And my sql:

```
/***************
 * Command
 ***************/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS command (
  command_word       VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  command_answer     VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  command_level      INT          NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
  command_createtime INT          NOT NULL
);

/***************
 * Preference
 ***************/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preference (
  preference_name  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  preference_value VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

Is this a syntaxe issue unsupported by PDO or simply that PDO doesn't support more than one request?

Comment: Your question has already been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: Oh, I missed that thread... Thanks