# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] when using fetchAll() on PDOStatement object

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Hie, I am learning how to use PHP,and have followed everything in the tutorials I am watching to the letter but I don't understand why I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
<?php

  try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql: host = localhost; dbname = tutorialdb", "root", "");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not connect to database.";
    exit;
  }


  try {
    $results = $db->query("USE mydatab; SELECT name, price, img FROM products ORDER BY sku asc");
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not retrieve data.";
    exit;
  }

  echo "<pre>"
  var_dump($results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

Any positive input will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Error code of SQLSTATE[HY000]?

Comment: try removing `USE mydatab;` and also add the `var_dump($results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` within the `try/catch` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use *query* and *exec* for one SQL statement at a time:

```
$db->exec("USE mydatab");
$results = $db->query("SELECT name, price, img FROM products ORDER BY sku asc");
```

It is possible to [do otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd), but there are some caveats. In general you could have multiple result sets, and you would need to indicate which of those you are retrieving. Life is a lot simpler if you just make separate calls.

Side-note: you can specify the UTF-8 charset in the connection string, like this:

```
 $db = new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=tutorialdb; charset=UTF8",
               "root", "");
```

So then you don't need this:

```
 $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```