# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a chat and I stumbled across an error. The error is:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO guildchat(guildID, playerID, message, `time`, chattime) VALUES(?, ?,' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sf\sexyutility.php:14
>   Stack trace:#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sf\sexyutility.php(14): PDO->prepare('SELECT @cht := ...')#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\req.php(2659): chatInsert('tewtewt', 53, 35)#2 {main}  thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\sf\sexyutility.php** on line **14**

The code is:

```
function chatInsert($message, $guild, $player){
    $time = time();
    $chattime = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare("SELECT @cht := Max(chattime) AS chattimer FROM guildchat WHERE guildID = :guild; INSERT INTO guildchat(guildID, playerID, message, `time`, chattime) VALUES(:guild, :player, :msg, :timers, @cht + 1)");
    $chattime->bindParam(":guild", $guild);
    $chattime->bindParam(":player", $player);
    $chattime->bindParam(":msg", $message);
    $chattime->bindParam(":timers", $time);
    $chattime->execute();
    return $chattime->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['chattimer'] + 1;
}
```

Comment: The error says your insert query has a syntax error. Now what's your question?

Comment: There's no guarantee that another running script won't insert a row with the same `chattime` between your `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries. You should investigate [transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and [isolation levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) if this is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you can only do one query at a time with PDO prepare. you're running two.
you will have to do it in 2 separate statements.</strike>

I guess I was wrong. Instead of removing the answer, I'll leave this link here as a reference.

[PDO Support for multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

It's supported, but with a few caveats.

Comment: According to [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO_MYSQL, PDO_MYSQLND)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd), PDO *does* in fact support more than one query at a time. Indeed, the OP's code works fine for me. However the syntax error does imply that this is the problem here...