# Making clear button for a hitcounter

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (isset($_POST['clear'])){
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM hitcounter","ALTER TABLE hitcounter AUTO_INCREMENT=0") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

I am trying to make a hitcounter that counts the amount of hits on a page. I have everything done except the clear button. I need the hit count to go back to 0 but i can't get it to work

Comment: You can't execute those two queries like that using `mysql_query()`. However, you can use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to execute multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon. Or you can even use `PDO`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6461110/5517143).

Comment: A bit off-topic... It seems odd to me that resetting auto_increment is involved at all. Plus, you'd probably want to reset it to `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS in mysql_connect's 5th argument. For more  information, refer this link:https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2009/08/08/mysql-stored-procedure-invocation-from-php/