# You have an error in your SQL syntax; creating a trigger in Joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, triggers

I am using mysql and I want to create a trigger in Joomla 3.4.8.

I have a sql code that **works** in mySQLWorkbench:
[image]

If I run it in a Joomla controller:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$sql = $db->getQuery(true);
$sql = 'LOCK TABLES id0ap_virtuemart_products WRITE; 
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_vm_products ;
        DELIMITER //
        CREATE TRIGGER update_vm_products 
        AFTER UPDATE
        ON id0ap_virtuemart_products FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO id0ap_virtuemart_notifications
        VALUES ("", NEW.virtuemart_product_id, "product","update");
        END //
        DELIMITER ;
        UNLOCK TABLES;';
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->execute();
```

I get:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_vm_products ; DELIMITER // ' at line 2 SQL=LOCK TABLES id0ap_virtuemart_products WRITE; DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_vm_products ; DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER update_vm_products AFTER UPDATE ON id0ap_virtuemart_products FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO id0ap_virtuemart_notifications VALUES ("", NEW.virtuemart_product_id, "product","update"); END // DELIMITER ; UNLOCK TABLES;

I can't find the problem. But I have dicovered something strange while I was trying to solve it. If I modify the sql deleting DELIMITERS and the DROP part:

```
$sql = 'CREATE TRIGGER update_vm_products 
        AFTER UPDATE
        ON id0ap_virtuemart_products FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO id0ap_virtuemart_notifications
        VALUES ("", NEW.virtuemart_product_id, "product","update");
        END ;';
```

whether you just try to create the trigger it works and create the trigger, only fails when you add the DROP part. Any idea? Is there an object-oriented way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO\_MYSQL, PDO\_MYSQLND)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

Comment: `LOCK TABLES ` and `DROP TRIGGER` are 2 different statements and you need to execute them individually prior the trigger, and also while executing the trigger via PDO or mysqli library you do not need the `delimiter` part. And finally `UNLOCK TABLES;` in a separate statement.Give it a try.

Comment: @middlestump I don't understand why is possible duplicate of that. The question has nothing to do with mine and the answer would not be possible in Joomla neither.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty It works! But now I have
$sql="query"; 
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->execute();
4 times, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Well there no more cleaner way other than mysqli multi query. Also since you are locking and unlocking the tables I don't think you really need them just take them out. Or in addition you can use transaction block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a joomla expert, but it seems that whatever mysql api joomla uses to execute the sql statements, can only execute 1 sql statement per call. Try to execute each sql statement on its own.

Comment: It works, but I don't like the result: http://prntscr.com/azrd6g

I have the same question I asked @Abhik Chakraborty, Is there a cleaner way to do this? Thanks

Comment: This is not a "dirty" way of executing queries and actually it is safer, than running all statements in one go. If you cannot execute more than one query in a single call, then it is very difficult to execute a successful sql injection attack.

Comment: The query will go like that there is no user input. It seems to be dirty to me in terms of coding, but if you can't do more than one query at once...

Comment: You may be able to execute more than one query in a single call, all depends on what mysql api joomla uses to access mysql, how the api and joomla is configured. However, that approach is still not "cleaner".