# One SQL query to create multiple tables with same sheet

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create multiple tables with same sheet in a single query like this

```
 $query ="CREATE TABLE users1, users2, users3 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    )";
```

then tried to execute it using PDO

```
$stmt->execute();
```

but didn't work, Then tried separating them

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE users1 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );
CREATE TABLE users2 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );
CREATE TABLE users3 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );
";
```

once with and without the `;`
but still give an error

Comment: Why do you want similar tables? Seems like a bad design.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE LIKE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html

Comment: @jarlh trying to make 3 types of pages with three different users

Comment: I agree with jarlh; a table for each user is not good design. The error you get pertains to a superfluous comma: `password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,)`

Comment: @HoneyBadger fixed that.

Comment: if you need different types of users, just add column `type` to your user table

Comment: @kRicha i'm not making a normal website concept in this part.

Comment: Nor a normal database concept... Have one table, add a column for type if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$sql = "
CREATE TABLE users1 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE users2 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE users3 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
";

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

You can read something interesting about pdo multi query :[PDO support for multiple queries (PDO_MYSQL, PDO_MYSQLND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

Comment: Can't we replace Primary Key with Unique or Index? or do we have to ALTER it?

Comment: i think  no need to do it. just check different between Unique and Primary key.

Comment: i trued  username VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL INDEX, BUT gave me a problem, I guss only Primary and Unique are possible in this part.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35821/possible-index-on-a-varchar-field-in-mysql