# Why aren't the values from my form inserting into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following form:

```
<form id ="classadderform" action="formsubmit.php" method="POST">
     <input type ="checkbox" name="note" value = "Note1"></input> 
     <input type="submit"  value="Click Me" style="width:300px;">
</form>
```

Upon submit, the code redirects to formsubmit.php. Part of the code there is the following:

```
$db = new mysqli("sql...byethost8.com", "b8_163//....(database info));
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
.......
if(isset($_POST['note'])){
    if($id){
        $db->query("UPDATE answers SET WordLevel = 'Difficult' WHERE user_id=$id"); //<<<UPDATES SUCCESSFULLY
        $notevalue=$_POST['note'];
        $db->query("INSERT INTO answers (user_id, ValueColumn) VALUES ($id,'$notevalue')");  //<<<<<DOESN'T UPDATE
```

The WordLevel column updates successfully, but the value of the input named `note` does not insert into the column titled `ValueColumn`. This was working in my code a few days ago but it somehow stopped working. I tried different iterations of single quotes around `$id` and `$notevalue` but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Can you chnage `'$notevalue'` to `"'" . $notevalue . "'"` and test ?

Comment: Thank you for the link @LeonardBrünings. I have read through that, which is how I originally got this to work a few days ago...but the insert function has stopped working on all of my forms and it's mind-boggling. If you look at the INSERT INTO statement that I posted, is there anything that jumps out at you?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu   When I do so, I get a `500 (Internal Server Error)` on the POST

Comment: How about enabling `error_reporting` or asking `mysqli_error` for once? Oh and let's not forget about parameter binding, btw.

Comment: One more thing you can do is assign the query to a variable, echo it and try to run the query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @mario I am trying my best to learn coding from the ground up without any education outside of the Internet, so please don't get nasty with me. I was not even aware that those existed; I Googled them and I'm not quite sure how to use them but I'm going to play around with them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @PrafullaKumarSahu. I'm not quite sure how to do that, but I'll see what I can find related to that online.

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO answers (user_id, ValueColumn) VALUES ($id,'$notevalue')"; echo $query; exit;` use this before insert query .

Comment: Is `user_id` column the primary key of your table?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu  Thank you. I tried using that before the insert query but everything ran the same way it did before. Am I supposed to see an error alert somewhere?

Comment: you should see the query and you should try running the query directly in phpmyadmin.

Comment: try this $query = "INSERT INTO answers (user_id, ValueColumn) VALUES ('$id','$notevalue')";

Comment: @Prags single quot can not parse variable .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help everyone. I don't even want to post what actually happened because it's so asininely stupid, but don't want to waste any more of your time on this issues.   I didn't realize that only the first 100 rows of the MYSQL database were visible so it didn't appear as though it was updating....Alas, I am ashamed haha. Thank you so much for your time everyone! Sorry again

Comment: @BeBo In that case I would suggest you to delete this question, otherwise question with *unaccepted* answer will be floating around SO as *open* question.

Answer (score 0):

Execute and clear before the second query.

O you can try concating queries together using semicolon

```
$db->query("FIRST QUERY ; SECOND QUERY");
```

If you dont need the output of first query.

[PDO multiple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

[mysqli multiple query](http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.multi-query.php)

[might also help real_query](http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.real-query.php)