# SQL Variable inside PHP Statement

Tags: php, mysql

My code:

```
 $sql = "SET @row_number = 0; SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, player, reinforcees, reinforcers FROM _KoT_villages WHERE o = '".$data[2]."' OR o = '".$data[4]."' ORDER BY CASE WHEN player = '".$user_class->id."' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, player,
>   reinforcees, reinforcers F' at line 1

When I echo the SQL statement, I get the following: `SET @row_number = 0; SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, player, reinforcees, reinforcers FROM _KoT_villages WHERE o = '1' OR o = '5' ORDER BY CASE WHEN player = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`

When I run that `echo`d statement through phpMyAdmin, it runs successfully, and gives me rows of results.

But why doesn't it work in a PHP statement? What's going on? How do I get PHP to do what SQL is doing?

And before anyone says I haven't tried to find the answer myself, if you Google `"sql variable" php site:stackoverflow.com`, every question I find is about accessing SQL results in PHP (i.e., loops) or inserting PHP variables in SQL, which is not what I need. I'm trying to insert an SQL variable into the SQL statement.

Also: I realize I should stop using MySQL, and am in the process of converting, but in order to quickly resolve a bug...I'm using MySQL.

Comment: You need to use something that supports MySQL multiple queries such  as  [`mysqli_multi_query`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) or [PDO with emulated statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL client in php expects individual statements

Open MySQL client

First Statement:

```
SET @row_number = 0
```

2nd Statement:

```
SELECT
   (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
   player,
   reinforcees,
   reinforcers
FROM
   _KoT_villages 
WHERE
   o = '".$data[2]."'
   OR o = '".$data[4]."'
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN player = '".$user_class->id."' THEN 1
    ELSE 2 
    END

$result = mysql_query( [2nd Statement] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Close MySQL client

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query` doesn't support multiple queries in one call. You would need to upgrade to `mysqli` or `PDO` to enable that. In the meantime though, you can implement what you want in a single query using a `CROSS JOIN` to initialise the `row_number` variable e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, player, reinforcees, reinforcers 
        FROM _KoT_villages 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0) r
        WHERE o = '".$data[2]."' OR o = '".$data[4]."' 
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN player = '".$user_class->id."' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END";
```