# How to fetch multiple table data with multiple queries to one data-table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I  fetch multiple table data with multiple queries to one jquery `dataTable`.
I want to fetch multiple table data of multiple queries to one data-table. can i do it with one query according to my code, I tried MySQL UNION, Not suitable for me.

**Fetch.php**

```
$query1 = "SELECT SUM(score) AS marks, from_date FROM table1 WHERE stat = 0 GROUP BY name ";
$statement = $db->prepare($query1);
$statement->execute();
$output = array('data' => array());
$count = $statement->rowCount();
if($count > 0) {

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ)) {

    $score = $row->marks;
    $date = $row->from_date;
    $Team = "Team 1";

$output['data'][] = array( $score,$date,$Team);     
 } // /while 
}// if num_rows

$query2 = "SELECT SUM(marks) AS marks, from_date FROM table2 WHERE stat = 0 GROUP BY name ";
$statement = $db->prepare($query2);
$statement->execute();
$output = array('data' => array());
$count = $statement->rowCount();
if($count > 0) {

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ)) {

    $score = $row->marks;
    $date = $row->from_date;
    $Team = "Team 2";

$output['data'][] = array( $score,$date,$Team);     
}
}// if num_rows
echo json_encode($output);
```

**html**

```
<table id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Team</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script>    
var score;
$(document).ready(function(){
score = $('#Table').DataTable({
    'ajax': 'fetch.php',
    'order': []
    });
});
</script>
```

[image: Table structer]

Comment: `from_date` is not aggregated. Can you show us tables structures, data sample and expected output ?

Comment: @Cid i want to fetch only first date of the group, how can i do it.

Comment: @Cid question edited with table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to fetch the result.

> **Note**:- Both table column should be the same, else you will get an error.

```
$result = [];
try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DB;charset=utf8mb4', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $conn->beginTransaction();

  $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(score) AS marks, from_date FROM table1 WHERE stat = 0 GROUP BY name UNION ALL SELECT SUM(marks) AS marks, from_date FROM table2 WHERE stat = 0 GROUP BY name ");
  $stmt1->execute();
  $result[]  = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $conn->commit();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}   
echo json_encode($result);
```

For the team variable, you can try

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS marks, from_date,'Team1' AS team FROM table1 WHERE stat = 0 GROUP BY name
```

and another query

```
SELECT SUM(marks) AS marks, from_date, 'Team2' AS team FROM table2 WHERE stat = 0 GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Can you convert it to PHP PDO.

Comment: @Mili refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: I am placing  `$Team = "Team 2";` to every query, How could i manage it.

Comment: @Mili use bindValue, check https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php