# SQLSTATE[HY000] on pdo SET variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have some issue on getting cumulative sum by month with PDO/MySQL, php 7.0 and mysql 5.5.

With multiple queries, i got "*Excention : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General errorvar*" as error. If i remove those "SET" lines, it disappear but i cannot have what i am trying to do.

```
$sql = "
SET @accInc := 0;
SET @accOut := 0;
SELECT
q1.y as year,
q1.m as month,
(@accInc := @accInc + q1.income) AS accInc,
(@accOut := @accOut + q1.outgo) AS outInc
FROM
    (SELECT
    YEAR(`date`) AS y,
    MONTH(`date`) AS m,
    SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as income,
    SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as outgo
    FROM `transaction`
    GROUP BY y, m
    ORDER BY y, m
    ) AS q1";
require("./pdo.php");
try {
    $req = $db->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute();
    $data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $acc[$row["year"]][$row["month"]] = array(
            "inc" => (float)$row["accInt"],
            "out" => (float)$row["accOut"]
        );
    }
} catch(PDOException $except) {
    printf("Excention : %s", $except->getMessage());
}
```

Thank you.

**Edit** : I had to set `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`
And isolate `SET` command. Now it works.

Comment: Do you have emulation on? Also `fetchAll` and then `foreach` is a waste of resources. Use `while` and a `fetch`.

Comment: Same error with `while -> fetch()`. The code above works on mysql commandline.

Comment: That was just a note about performance. It wouldn't resolve the main issue. Back to the first question, `Do you have emulation on?`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO\_MYSQL, PDO\_MYSQLND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

Comment: Sorry. Ok i add `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, no error but null result.

Comment: Issue solved by setting `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false` and isolating `SET @accInc := 0` and `SET @accOut := 0`. Thank you.