# set entire column to zero and then update a specific row

Tags: php, mysql

I want firstly antire `def` column set to be `0` except the row where id is a variable (this should be `1`).

```
$sql = "update rolls set def = 0, def = 1 where id = :aid";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([":aid" => $id]);
```

result - the first part - set to `0` - doesn't work;

Any help?

Comment: Maybe `where id = :aid and def <>1`? or what do you mean by `id is a variable`, `$id` is always a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate into 2 queries

```
// Query one ; query two
$sql = "update rolls set def = 0; update rolls set def = 1 where id = :aid";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([":aid" => $id]);
```

Comment: are you sure there is no `single query` way?

Comment: Not really sure, I've never tried to update a table this way. Searching for `mysql update subquery` didn't get useful results.

Comment: Maybe this could be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: yes, it works - `$sql = "update rolls set def = 0; update rolls set def = 1 where id = :aid;";` - you should update your answer