# is it possible to create SQL table and insert data at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

when i removed the create table it is working, but is it possible to do this on code?

[image]

here is the code

```
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE student (
        student_id INT,
        name VARCHAR(20),
        major VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
    )
    
    INSERT INTO student VALUE(1, 'Jack', 'biology')";
    
    if ($connect -> query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New Table Created! <br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error : " . $sql . " <br><br>" . $connect -> error . "<br><br>";
    }
    
    echo "Connected Successfully!";
```

Here is the error when i didn't removed the create table

> Error : CREATE TABLE student ( student_id INT, name VARCHAR(20), major VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY(student_id) ); INSERT INTO student VALUE(2, 'kate', 'sociology')

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO student VALUE(2, 'kate', 'sociology')' at line 8

Comment: Yes it's possible. What's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: It is not inserting data when the create table is not remove it saysnsyntax error

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you are actually running with problem. Also write the exactly error message.

Comment: That's the code that i actually running

Comment: You have a typo in your insert statement. It is VALUES not VALUE. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-statement.aspx

Comment: Or you run a query for each statement (create, then insert), or do some trick like what people do in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: I am not familiar with Maria DB or your SQL version. Please look on how to provide a minimal reproducible example. But usually the `create table` command requires the `select` statement after the name of the table and before listing the variables.

Comment: [Don't paste images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: i'm asking if i can do the code in the picture in ```$sql```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a table and insert data into it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053190/how-to-create-a-table-and-insert-data-into-it)

Comment: it give me an idea thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 typos in your code:

- Missing ";" between the CREATE and INSERT statements.
- INSERT statement uses VALUES, not VALUE.

  ```
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE student (
       student_id INT,
       name VARCHAR(20),
       major VARCHAR(20),
       PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
   );

   INSERT INTO student VALUES (1, 'Jack', 'biology')";
  ```

Aside from that, check the official docs for [mysqli Multiple statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) and [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) since as mentioned in the first document:

> The API functions mysqli_query() and mysqli_real_query() do not set a connection flag necessary for activating multi queries in the server. An extra API call is used for multiple statements to reduce the likeliness of accidental SQL injection attacks.

Or you can also change your code to run each query individually.

Comment: I jist found out about multi_query($sql) i'm gonna try that later thanks to all who answer my question!

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of `mysqli_multi_query()`. Clearly, there is no reason to use it in this scenario.